# Messages are not showing, Firebase Chat

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

After message sending it isn't showing. But I'm receiving the message in Firebase Database. What's wrong with it? Have you any suggestions?

[image: I sent a message, but it isn't showing]

MainActivity.class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
private final static String TAG = "LOG";
EditText input;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    checkAuth();
    input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

    FloatingActionButton fab =
            (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (input.getText().toString().equals(null) && input.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Mesage is empty");
            } else {
                // Read the input field and push a new instance
                // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .push()
                        .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                        .getCurrentUser()
                                        .getDisplayName())

                        );
                displayChatMessages();
                // Clear the input
                input.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void displayChatMessages() {
    ListView listOfMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

    //Suppose you want to retrieve "chats" in your Firebase DB:
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
            .setLayout(R.layout.message)
            .build();
    //Finally you pass them to the constructor here:
    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options){
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
            Log.i(TAG, model.getMessageUser() + ": " + model.getMessageText());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void checkAuth(){
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
     currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        displayChatMessages();
        ///
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    checkAuth();
  }
  }
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/fab"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fab">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

message.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/message_user"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message_user"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/message_time" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message_user"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/message_text"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

*By the way, it's not a good solution to obey type more text.*
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: I recommend doing some basic debugging yourself, such as placing a breakpoint on the first line inside `populateView` and then running in the debugger. Does it reach that line? If not, no data is coming in from your database. If it does, step through the code line by line and check the value of each variable on each line to see that it matches with what you expect. Also check the logcat for relevant messages.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.